# Change Background Color of button in OSX

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, nsbutton

I want to change the background color of a button in a dialog to red, if a specific option is enabled. I tried

```
run.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
```

but nothing happens. (run is the name of the button) There are similar questions, but no answers. And these questions are years old. I hope there is a simple solution, bc. this seems not an unusual approach. Again, it belongs to OSX (and SWIFT 3).

Answer (score 0):

`NSButton` doesn't have a `backgroundColor` property, but it's `CALayer` does. So, to get the same effect you could do the following:

```
myButton.wantsLayer = true
myButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: My button is of type NSButtonCell. It has no property "wantsLayer". How should I get there?